# using SQL Server 2008 instead of SQLite in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have created an application that makes use of database.

Can I use SQL Server 2008 in the iPhone to store data instead of SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not supply MS SQL server 2008 with IOS and you can't install it as Microsoft does not supply an ARM based version running on IOS. You are stuck with sqlite as the database engine on the iPhone. You can connect to SQL Server running on an external website using SOAP or a RESTFUL inteface.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested you can use a web service call to your SQL 2008 database from your iOS application, if you are going to keep the data on the server side.

However, you should investigate Core Data and not use SQLlite if you are going to implement a client-side solution. Core Data is the preferred solution.

If you are familiar with Entity Framework then some of the concepts of Core Data should be easier to follow.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650

Answer (score 0):

NO,You can'nt use **sql server 2008**,
For any DB operation you will have to use **sqllite** in iPhone.